# Replace words except the ones inside braces

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, replace, markdown

I have a markdown string like this
`Status of app [TODO app](url.com/apps/list?appid=q1w2e3) has been changed to completed.`
I want to wrap searched words (see the function below) with `<mark></mark>`, but skip the link `(url.com/apps/list?appid=q1w2e3)` so I will have `TODO <mark>app</mark>` but not `url.com/<mark>app</mark>s/list?<mark>app</mark>id=q1w2e3`

How can I achieve that?

The code I'm using to add `mark`s:

```js
const garbage = /[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g;

const highlightMarkdown = (originalString = '', highlight = '') => {
  highlight = highlight.trim();
  if (!highlight) return originalString;

  const wordsToFind = highlight.replace(garbage, '').split(' ');

  const result = wordsToFind.reduce((result, word) => {
    const re = new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'gi');

    return result.replace(re, (word) => `<mark>${word}</mark>`);
  }, originalString);

  return result;
};

const result = highlightMarkdown(
  `Status of app [TODO app](url.com/apps/list?appid=q1w2e3) has been changed to completed.`,
  'app'
);

console.log(result);
```

**UPD**
I'm trying to `mark` not only `app` but also `<mark>app</mark>s`, because this function is for user's search

Comment: You should do this on the DOM level, _after_ you have rendered this markdown into HTML.

Comment: ``const re = new RegExp(`(\\[^\\][]*]\\([^()]*\\))|${word}`, 'gi');`` and then ``return result.replace(re, (x,y) => y || `<mark>${x}</mark>`);``

Comment: @CBroe I will try, I will not find a better solution (because I use React)

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew doesn't work :(

Comment: ``const re = new RegExp(`(\\[[^\\][]*]\\([^()]*\\))|${word}`, 'gi');    return result.replace(re, (x,y) => y || `<mark>${x}</mark>`);`` works. `[` was missing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good. Can you please make `app` inside link text also marked like `[TODO <mark>app</mark>]` ?

Comment: Just remove ``\\[[^\\][]*]``

Answer (score 1):

It may be enough to ensure that the word is not preceded/followed by alpha numericals, nor some specific characters like `/`, `&`, `=` and `-`.

Also, you can do this with *one* regex, and don't need a callback as argument for the `replace` call. You can use a back-reference `$&`:

```js
const garbage = /[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g;

const highlightMarkdown = (originalString = '', highlight = '') => {
  highlight = highlight.trim().replace(garbage, '');
  if (!highlight) return originalString;

  const wordsToFind = highlight.replace(/ /g, '|');
  const re = new RegExp(`(?<![/=&-])\\b(${wordsToFind})\\b(?![/=&-])`, 'gi');
  return originalString.replace(re, '<mark>$&</mark>');
};

const result = highlightMarkdown(
  `Status of app [TODO app](url.com/apps/list?appid=q1w2e3) has been changed to completed.`,
  'app'
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice  way of replacing many words with or `|` operator instead of `split` and `reduce` and also you treat the case when `/app/` in the link using lookbehind!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the flag `g` but it will just change the first `app` matched not the one inside brackets *[TODO app]*,
to do So you can define a variable times and define how many times you want the word `app` be replaced!

```js
const garbage = /[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g;

const highlightMarkdown = (originalString = '', highlight = '') => {
  highlight = highlight.trim();
  if (!highlight) return originalString;

  const wordsToFind = highlight.replace(garbage, '').split(' ');
  let times = 0; // Define here
  const result = wordsToFind.reduce((result, word) => {
    const re = new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'gi');

    return result.replace(re, (word) => {
        if(times<2){
            times++; // increment here
            return `<mark>${word}</mark>`;
        }
        return word;
        
    });
  }, originalString);

  return result;
};

const result = highlightMarkdown(
  `Status of app [TODO app](url.com/apps/list?appid=q1w2e3) has been changed to completed.`,
  'app'
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The problem is that it will be broken if you change the sequence in the text

Comment: Yes it will change only the first two app, I provided  a better answer using boundaries `\b`!

Answer (score 0):

Better Solution use word boundary `\b`

```js
const re = new RegExp(`\\b(${word})\\b`, 'gi');
```

Comment: If the url has `/app/` it will not be enough as a measure...

Comment: Nice note, if there is such link contain `/app/` it will be affected since `/` considered word boundary.